# C# Linq non-vowels

Tags: c#, linq

From the given string

(i.e)

```
string str = "dry sky one two try";
var nonVowels = str.Split(' ').Where(x => !x.Contains("aeiou")); (not working).
```

How can i extract non-vowel words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var nonVowels = str.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Intersect("aeiou").Count() == 0);
```

String.Contains requires you to pass a single char.  Using Enumerable.Contains would only work for a single char, as well - so you'd need multiple calls.  Intersect should handle this case.

Comment: Thanks you very much.Suppose if i were to use C# 2.0 how can i handle it?

Comment: The same way, but call the extension methods as static methods and use an anonymous delegate in stead of the lambda: `delegate(string x) { return Enumerable.Count(Enumerable.Intersect(x, "aeiou")) == 0; }`

Answer (score 5):

Come on now y'all. [`IndexOfAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx) is where it's at. :)

```
// if this is public, it's vulnerable to people setting individual elements.
private static readonly char[] Vowels = "aeiou".ToCharArray();

// C# 3
var nonVowelWorks = str.Split(' ').Where(word => word.IndexOfAny(Vowels) < 0);

// C# 2
List<string> words = new List<string>(str.Split(' '));
words.RemoveAll(delegate(string word) { return word.IndexOfAny(Vowels) >= 0; });
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var nonVowelWords = str.Split(' ').Where(x => Regex.Match(x, @"[aeiou]") == null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "dry sky one two try";
var nonVowels = str.ToCharArray()
    .Where(x => !new [] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}.Contains(x));
```

Comment: Should be `str.Split`, not `ToCharArray`.